# Newtonsoft DeserializeObject "True" Case Insensitive

Tags: c#, json

I want to deserialize a simple string `"True"` to boolean true using `Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` method like this:

```
var b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("True");
```

but it gives me an error.
`'Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: T. Path '', line 0, position 0.'`

I heard `Newtonsoft uses case insensitive deserialization by default`

why is this error?

Comment: Why not just use `bool.Parse("True")`?

Comment: JSON is generally case sensitive, e.g. having two attribute names that differ only in case is valid.

Comment: @Magnus: Okay, that really *is* confusing. Deleting my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Valid JSON values are:

- object (`{ ... }`)
- array (`[...]`)
- number (`1`)
- string (`"String"`)
- boolean (either `true` or `false`, NOT `True` or `False`)
- null (`null`)

For that reason, "true" is a valid JSON representing single boolean value.

However, "True" is not valid json, it does not represent any of the above values according to specification (it does not represent string, because in this case it should have been ""True"" (with quotes).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, a bare `True` value is simply not valid JSON. So there is no reason for JSON.Net to accept it.

However, it will accept a string value `"True"` or `"true"` in place of a `bool`

```cs
var b = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"""True""");

// returns true

var f = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(@"""False""");

// returns false
```

[dotnetfiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/66gWfm)